# Handling LocalDate in SpringBoot

Tags: datetime, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new in SpringBoot. I am facing some issues in handling of LocalDate.

I am following below link for it.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/03/dealing-javas-localdatetime-jpa.html

I have created a class in my code.

```
    @Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>{

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(localDateTime)
                .map(Timestamp::valueOf)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(timestamp)
                .map(Timestamp::toLocalDateTime)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Now in request i am getting the date in string format.

```
@GetMapping(value = "getAppointmentListByDate")
public ResponseEntity<List<AppointmentDTO>> getAppointmentListByDate(@RequestParam("fromDate") String date)
        throws CustomException {

}
```

Now here my concern is that how can i use this string date ?

In database i have defined this date in timestamp data type.

Comment: So what's the error message?

Comment: @akuma8 No error message. my question is that how can i use date string inside getAppointmentListByDate() method.

Comment: converting a string to localdatetime http://www.java67.com/2016/04/how-to-convert-string-to-localdatetime-in-java8-example.html

Comment: latest spring boot 2.0 has buildin converters and it should be possible to use the LocalDateTime directly as request parameter. If use your own string format for dates, then you need to handle it yourself.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Thanks . Now i am using LocaleDateTime directly as a parameter. Its solve my issue.      I am facing one more issue when i returning data back in response then date comes is in array form.   like "requestedAppointmentDateTime": [
            2018,
            8,
            16,
            15,
            41,
            52,
            474000000
        ],

Comment: This depends on the converter. You can try the ``toString`` method of the ``LocalDateTime``. For a more custom converstion you can use ``DateTimeFormatter``.